# Powering up grid of 20 Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, raspberry-pi

I need to power up a grid of 20 RPi3. Each RPi3 required 5V 2.4A. So, in total is it about 50A.

According to my tests it doesn't drain more that 1.2A. I think it is because I don't use any USB or WiFi.

So, I want to have one or two power supples for all of them. Since I have very little EE experience I just made a simple search in internet for 5V 50A power supply.

So far I like power supplies from company called: MEAN WELL.

I like these:

- [SP-240-5](http://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=SP-240)
- [RSP-320-5](http://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=RSP-320)
- [HRPG-300-5](http://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=HRPG-300)

---

Questions:

1. Please tell me where it is ok just wire up my RPi3 in parallel with 18 AWG via Micro USB to one of the power supply of my choose above?
2. What I should consider additionally, maybe I am missing something important (very little EE experience and very serious amperage)?
3. If you know better solution - please tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ The SP-240-5 does only 45 Amps so I would avoid that one.

 Then yes, you can wire them up. Your approach of sticking to the 50Amps although it 'looks like' you get away with less is correct. The load also depends greatly on what you are running on the ARM cores so don't assume that as long as you don't use USB/WiFi/Bluetooth, your OK. I assume you are not connecting other stuff like cameras HATs etc. 

2/ I would add a fuse per Pi. Yes, the Pi has an internal fuse but with 50/60A I personally would like to have a small glass cylinder with a thin wire in front of each PI.

You can only switch them all on or off. Maybe add an on/off switch in front of each.